# hello world prog in C with Xcode got a build failed

Tags: c, xcode4.3

I am trying to learn C and I have just installed Xcode on my Mac. I wanted to run the first program that was already written

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and got build failed. 
I created a program in C. The libraries have been downloaded.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please explain the "...and got build failed" part in more detail? What was the error message? You can edit your question to provide this detail, it's very important to figuring out what's going on.

Comment: FYI, use <ctrl>+K to mark code to have code formatting - I've removed the space in the include for you.

Comment: Usually `argv` is `char *argv[]`, not `const char *argv[]` - even though making it const is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to learn C or Objective-C? As far as I know, XCode is only appropriate for Objective C.

Also, can you post your compiler error, that will help alot.